# convert javascript regex to php

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I have the following regular expression:

```
RegExp("http://www.amazon.com/([\\w-]+/)?(dp|gp/product)/(\\w+/)?(\\w{10})");
```

Written in javascript.

How can I get it to work with PHP's `preg_match_all`? What are the differences as far as regular expressions go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
preg_match_all('#http://www.amazon.com/([\w-]+/)?(dp|gp/product)/(\w+/)?(\w{10})#', $data, $matches);
```

When you use the JavaScript `RegExp` constructor with a string, all backslashes have to be escaped with another backslash. This is not the case with PHP.

And normally you would use `/` as the delimiter for the regex, but as in this case you have a lot of `/` in your search string it is wiser to use some other delimiter so you don't have to escape every slash with a backslash. In this case I used the pound sign as a delimiter.

Comment: Commenting on an old answer, but do you know of any automated converters for Javascript Regex syntax to PHP regex syntax?